# Interpretation of "background colour index" in GIF specification

Tags: gif, specifications, animated-gif

If you look in the [GIF specification](https://www.w3.org/Graphics/GIF/spec-gif89a.txt) and search for "Background Color Index", you see the following description:

> vii) Background Color Index - Index into the Global Color Table for
>   the Background Color. The Background Color is the color used for those
>   pixels on the screen that are not covered by an image. If the Global
>   Color Table Flag is set to (zero), this field should be zero and
>   should be ignored.

There is an ambiguity here, which is that if the "Global Color Table Flag" is set to zero and this field is ignored, then it is undefined what background colour of a GIF actually should be if the image data itself does not cover the entire image area. This possible because every image data block specifies left/right/width/height independently and there is no requirement that every pixel must be encoded by the image data.

Am I misinterpreting this? If not, then in the presence of this ambiguity, what is the de facto behaviour of GIF implementations today?

Answer (score 3):

The background color index is often ignored by decoders (including some modern browsers), whereas GDI+ (eg. Windows Paint or .NET WinForms controls) respect it. GDI+ handles it like this:

- If there is no global palette, *OR* the first frame has transparency (the Transparent Color Flag is set in the Graphic Control Extension), then the background is transparent
- If there is a global palette *AND* the first frame has no transparency (there is no Graphic Control Extension for the first frame, or the Transparent Color Flag is not set for it), then it means a color index from the global palette and is significant only if not the whole virtual screen area is covered by the first image, or when the "Restore to background color" disposal method is set for a frame. In latter case it does not matter if a possibly existing local palette does not contain the background color.

To demonstrate its effect I created a simple animation of two frames with [my encoder](https://github.com/koszeggy/KGySoft.Drawing#advanced-gif-encoder-with-high-color-support), and then played with some settings (feel free to download the images and see their content in a file viewer because I added some textual hint in the files). You can use [this app](https://github.com/koszeggy/KGySoft.Drawing.Tools) to see the animations in a Win32 app using GDI+ rendering.

Common properties:

- All images have a global palette so the the background color can be set.
- The background color is set to green.
- The Virtual Screen Size is 64x64 pixels
- The first frame is 48x48 pixels
- The second frame is 32x32 pixels

| The animation rendered by your browser | The 2nd frame by GDI+ | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] | None of the frames are transparent, there is no clear. |
| [image] | [image] | Both frames are transparent, there is no clear. |
| [image] | [image] | Only the 2nd frame is transparent, there is a clear after the first frame. |

Comment: AFAICS Microsoft is at it yet again, breaking the de-facto standards.

Comment: I would not call something "breaking" that respects the specification (which is admittedly vague by the way) more than others. And unlike modern browsers, it can differentiate animations from multi-layered still images. I think the moral of the story is that one should not rely on the back color index in today's applications or web usage.

Comment: Just in case: I agree wholeheartedly that 0ms delays are to be treated as parts of a single frame. This is however not the case with the vast majority of GIF decoders. The thing is, even if some interpretation of the standard feels more correct than the consensus interpretation, it is generally not encouraged to implement the former instead of the latter, unless user confusion is the desired outcome.

Comment: Actually it is also a bit complicated (as everything with de-facto standards). There are [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21791012/5114784) where 0 delays should be animated. GDI+ (or more precisely, the WIC GIF decoder) handles it quite effectively: if there is no `NETSCAPE` application extension, then 0 delay really means no delay; otherwise, a default 100ms is used. Browsers tend to interpret zeros as 100ms delays, no matter what.

Answer (score 1):

For the example, Safari uses black as the background. With Win10 photo viewer it's hard to tell, as it uses a black background anyway. Chrome, IE and Edge use white.
The spec doesn't define the behaviour when there's no background colour and you need one, so I guess arbitrary choices is what you'll get, though I vote for transparent being the most sensible.

Comment: (This post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer, or just post it as a comment to the question).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the ambiguity is indeed present. Background color is largely a derelict of GIF87a, currently only necessary for 'Restore Background' frame blending mode.

By now, all decoders I have seen treat pixels not belonging to any frame as transparent even if transparency flags in all of the frames are zeroed.

Consider this GIF, for example:

[image]

See how your browser interprets it? The whole background is transparent.

P.S.: in case it does not loop, reload the page using Ctrl+F5.

Comment: _"The whole background is transparent"_ - no, this image uses no transparency. All frames use the `GCE_DISPOSAL_INPLACE` disposal control code to prevent clearing the image between the frames. _"in case it does not loop"_ - it **must not** loop, as it doesn't even contain the `NETSCAPE2.0` extension. And actually it should not be animated at all (all frames have 0 delays, which is interpreted as 100ms by most browsers but without the repeat info these should be interpreted as layers rather than animation frames). Paint handles it correctly though, shows the whole high color image at once.

Comment: @GyörgyKőszeg 1. Okay, so the image does not use transparency, but then how come the background is visible through it while it renders? Must be a miracle. 2. Wrong, all animated GIFs loop indefinitely by default, which was the case long before Netscape introduced its custom extension. 3. There is a difference between the declared standard and the de-facto standard — e.g. GIF graphic control extension header includes a special flag that allows GIFs to require user input to proceed to the next frame, but no one ever respects that flag nowadays.

Comment: No need to be rude, I wasn't disrespectful either. This is a well known high color GIF example and has nothing to do with transparency. GDI+ handles it correctly so if you open it in Paint the whole image is displayed immediately (but try to open an animated GIF and you will see the first frame only). If browsers animate it, you see a transparent background until the whole virtual screen area is filled just because there is no global palette. But the question was about the backround color index, not transparency (see also my answer for details).

Comment: @GyörgyKőszeg I would never be «rude» if you didn`t assume that the implementations of whatever (GIF included) done by Microsoft are the way to go. Since its inception, MS is infamous for breaking the de-facto standards in a relentless push to make other implementations «obsolete». Embrace, Extend, Exterminate.