# Determing the color of uncovered GIF pixels

Tags: gif, specifications

Here is a GIF containing just one image, 75 pixels wide.

[image: strips of color]

The image has an Image Descriptor with an Image Left Position of 25.

So the leftmost 25 pixels of the image are not covered. Since the [GIF specification](https://www.w3.org/Graphics/GIF/spec-gif89a.txt) states that

> The Background Color is the color used for those pixels on the screen that are not covered by an image.

and the Background Color Index is 0, and the first entry in the palette is (0, 255, 0), I would think those leftmost 25 pixels should be green.

Instead, the browser renders those pixels as transparent.

Can anyone tell me why this is? Have I missed something in the specification?

Comment: Pixels are encoded as an index into the palette, and one entry is designated as "transparent" (not covered by the image), which is why the browser renders it that way. In principle, nothing prevents a one entry in the palette to have the same color as any other, it's just that it's at a different index. So I'm guessing that the green strip references a different entry that happens to have the same color. Now, I'm not entirely sure *why* the transparent index has a color associated with it, but I suspect it has something to do with the Disposal Method flag and how animated gifs clear the frame.

Comment: '"transparent" (not covered by the image)' - the way that I read the spec, it is the background color that is used when something is outside of the image. If you can explain to me why transparency is used instead of the background color, that would answer my question.

Comment: Aaah, I think I misinterpreted it, sorry. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48669313): "Background color is largely a derelict of GIF87a, currently only necessary for 'Restore Background' frame blending mode". It goes on to say: "all decoders I have seen treat pixels not belonging to any frame as transparent even if transparency flags in all of the frames are zeroed" - so it may be that what you've encountered here is unofficial but universally accepted behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to find https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/anim_basics/#dispose. In discussing why ImageMagick uses transparency for disposal method 2, it states (emphasis mine)

> There is some thinking that rather than clearing the overlaid area to the transparent color, this disposal should clear it to the 'background' color meta-data setting stored in the GIF animation. In fact the old "Netscape" browser (version 2 and 3), did exactly that. But then it also failed to implement the 'Previous' dispose method correctly.
>
> **On the other hand the initial canvas should also be set from the formats 'background' color too, and that is also not done.** However all modern web browsers clear just the area that was last overlaid to transparency, as such this is now accepted practice, and what IM now follows.